Unable to decrypt message encrypted with react-native-rsa
I have a backend service utility (based on this gist) which looks like this:
import crypto from 'crypto';

interface KeyPair {
    publicKey: string;
    privateKey: string;
}

export class RSAController {
    static async generateKeys(): Promise<KeyPair> {
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            crypto.generateKeyPair(
                'rsa',
                {
                    modulusLength: 2048,
                },
                (err, publicKeyObject, privateKeyObject) => {
                    if (err) rej(err);

                    const publicKey = publicKeyObject.export({
                        type: 'pkcs1',
                        format: 'pem',
                    });
                    const privateKey = privateKeyObject.export({
                        type: 'pkcs1',
                        format: 'pem',
                    });

                    res({
                        publicKey: publicKey as string,
                        privateKey: privateKey as string,
                    });
                },
            );
        });
    }

    static encrypt({ data, publicKey }: { data: string; publicKey: string }) {
        const encryptedData = crypto.publicEncrypt(
            {
                key: publicKey,
                padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING,
                oaepHash: 'sha256',
            },
            Buffer.from(data),
        );

        return encryptedData.toString('base64');
    }

    static decrypt({ encryptedData, privateKey }: { encryptedData: string; privateKey: string }) {
        const decryptedData = crypto.privateDecrypt(
            {
                key: privateKey,
                padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING,
                oaepHash: 'sha256',
            },
            Buffer.from(encryptedData, 'base64'),
        );

        return decryptedData.toString();
    }
}

What works is if I try to encrypt and subsequently decrypt a string on the backend:
const { privateKey, publicKey } = await RSAController.generateKeys();
const encryptedData = await RSAController.encrypt({ data: 'hello world', publicKey });
console.log('encryptedData', encryptedData);
const decryptedData = await RSAController.decrypt({ encryptedData, privateKey });
console.log('decryptedData', decryptedData); // works fine, I see "hello world"

But I'm also using the react-native-rsa-native library, which encrypts on the frontend first, before sending out the message to the backend.
This is where my problem arises, because encrypting and subsequently decrypting works fine if I'm just using RSAController, but if I encrypt with the client libary's RSA.encrypt method, and then try to decrypt this on the backend with RSAController, I catch the error,
error:02000079:rsa routines::oaep decoding error

What am I doing wrong here?

You haven't shown any code from the client, but the code of the RSA library that you point to only uses RSA with the badly named "PKCS#1 padding" rather than OAEP padding which was introduced in PKCS#1 v2.
When enabling cryptography it is important that you first understand the basics of cryptography so you can see if the schemes that you are using match. You cannot just read "RSA" or "AES" and expect the implementations to match.

Furthermore, I would highly recommend to research which libraries to use. The react RSA lib you are using seems to be an abandoned single person project which has open issues going back all the way to 2018 and hasn't seen any significant edits for 3 years. The Github page literally asks for a maintainer.
It's what I would call a "wrapper library" that wraps common low level functionality for convenience - it is mainly compatible with itself. It doesn't even list what scheme it is implementing or any limitations. This is especially important because it uses the somewhat vulnerable PKCS#1 scheme instead of OAEP. Neither does it use hybrid encryption which would allow any sized messages.
